# Is there a terminal on ubuntu that has a password manager like iterm2?

Tags: gui

Is there a terminal on Ubuntu that offers a password manager feature like iterm2 on macOS ?

Like the ability to auto-fill your sudo / ssh passwords ?

Comment: For ssh: `.ssh/config` and keys, for `sudo` use `sudo visudo` to use passwordless `sudo`. Imo, auto-fill passwords is not a very good idea.

Comment: @RoVo having passwordless looks even worse, using same sudo password, again very bad, so having them in a vault looks like a decent idea, moving them with copy/paste each time is the bad part.

Comment: Search how to use visudo to edit /etc/sudoers file, you can configure certain commands not ask for password. As mentioned above its not good idea.